# Django: why does my login view/form and next redirect not work in safari?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am having problems with a Django login form in Safari which runs successfully in both Chrome and IE.

When used in Chrome/IE the form both returns the username/password correctly (when needed) and when a correct username/password is entered logs the user in and redirects to {{next}}.

Under safari, the username/password error also works correctly, but when a valid username and password is entered the user is redirected back to the login page instead of {{next}}.

Here is my login view:

```
def login_user(request):
   next = request.GET['next']

   state = ""
   username = password = ""

   if request.POST:
       username = request.POST.get('username')
       password = request.POST.get('password')

       user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
       if user is not None:
           if user.is_active:
               login(request, user)

               return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
           else:
               state = "You're account is not active"
       else:
           state = "Your're username and/or password are incorrect."

    return render_to_response('access/login.html', { 'state' : state }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the form from the login template:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<label for="username">username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>      
    <label for="password">password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />

    <p><strong>{{ state }}</strong></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, either `HttpResponseRedirect` is not working or `next` value is wrong.

I've used HttpResponseRedirect many times and didnt get any problem so far.

Let's see the 2nd option. As you pass it in the URL parameter, the browser can escape some character. So the result you get in not working. Maybe if you print next in console, you'll see what's wrong?

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my login template (located in templates/registration/login.html), which works:

```
{% load url from future %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

By just hooking into the django auth plugin it "just works" for me without needing a custom view method.